# IOS write javascript on web have to use 'completetion(result)'

Tags: javascript, ios

i ues my iphone want to write js to check in at work evary day

it's my simpe js code

```
const glogin = $('.loginBtn.loginBtn--google');
glogin.onclick();
const checkOut = $('#checkOut');
checkOut.click();
```

it's can't use
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PP7QM.jpg)

what can i do ??

i try add completetion(result)

```
var result = function(){
const glogin = $('.loginBtn.loginBtn--google'); glogin.onclick(); 
const checkOut = $('#checkOut'); checkOut.click();
}
completetion(result)
```

also cant use

i want it can use,thanks

Comment: Is this question about the iOS app called [Scriptable](https://scriptable.app/)?

Comment: yes,ios has tools to automatically execute js,in the shortcut

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://docs.scriptable.app/webview/#-evaluatejavascript)?

Comment: you said ios doc?or js?